# Inputted number will add to API URL Key value via passing variable from page.html to services.ts

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic, Angular and Typescript, is it possible for the inputted number will add to the API URL as one of the key value? I followed this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) under Key event filtering (with key.enter)

Here's my  page.html

```
    <ion-input placeholder="Number" [(ngModel)]="myNum"  (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"></ion-input>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!error; else errorContent">

    <p *ngFor="let order of orders; let i=index;">
      <ion-item *ngIf="i==0">Number : <b>{{ order?.Number }}</b></ion-item>

      <ion-item class="listDetails">

        <p class="listTitle">
          {{order?.status }}
          <br />
          <a>
            {{ order?.date | date: 'MMM dd, yyyy' }}
            <br />
            {{ order?.time }}
          </a>
        </p>

        <p class="listComment">
          {{ order?.comment }}
        </p>

      </ion-item>
```

and here's my example API URL.

> 'https://myapi.com/FoodDeliveryTracking?&userName=myuser&password=mypass&MyNumber='+myNum

Here's my page.ts

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: HttpClient) {
  this.data = '';
  this.error = '';
 }


orders= [];
ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Load the data
  this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe( //comment this if you will use local data
    data => {
      // Takes data into in single Array and print 
      this.orders = data.output.Result.FoodOrderTracking;
    },
    err => {
      // Set the error information to display in the template
      this.error = `An error occurred, the data could not be retrieved: Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    }
  );
}

    this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Remote Data:");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  onEnter () {

    this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe(data=>
    {
      console.log('data', data)
    })
  }
```

Here's my data.services.ts which is for fetching the data from my API url.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  myNum = ''
  onEnter (docNum: string) {this.myNum = myNum}
  apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/https://myapi.com/FoodDeliveryTracking?&userName=myuser&password=mypass&MyNumber='+myNum';
  apiKey = ''; // <-- Enter your own key here!



    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}


    getRemoteData(){
      let headers = new HttpHeaders({'apiKey': this.apiKey});
      headers.append('Accept','application/json');
      headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
      headers.append('content-type','application/json');
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers: headers});
    }


}
```

How can I pass a variable from my input on my page.html to the services.ts? Is it possible? So that in my services.ts

> myNum = Data entered from the ion-input on my html.page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Use databinding in your html template

```
 <ion-input placeholder="Number" [(ngModel)]="myNum"  (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"></ion-input>
```

**component.ts**

Modify `onEnter` on your page to call the service

```
onEnter () {

  this.dataService.getRemoteData(this.myNum).subscribe(data=>
  {
    console.log('data', data)
  })
}
```

**dataservice.ts**

Just use base url for API

```
 apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/https://myapi.com/FoodDeliveryTracking';
```

Modify `getRemoteData` to use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) to send query parameters.

```
getRemoteData(myNum: string){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'apiKey': this.apiKey});

    //Set query string parameters
    let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('MyNumber', myNum) 
    .set('userName','myuser')
    .set('password','mypass');

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers, params}).subscribe(data =>console.log('data', data));
}
```

Here is a [demo code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hpdv2u?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts). Of cours the http request does not succeed since the api url does not exist, but you can see in the network debugger that it's sending all parameters

Comment: Thanks for this! but it only updates in the console, not in the UI it doesnt show the data in the UI

Comment: Ohh nevermind I got it, I just need to put my data in array under OnEnter(). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I did not know what kind of data you had. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are updating `myNum`, but `apiUrl` stays the same.

To fix that, you can make `apiUrl` a computed property, like this:

```
get apiUrl () {
  return 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/https://myapi.com/FoodDeliveryTracking?&userName=myuser&password=mypass&MyNumber=' + this.myNum';
}
```

This will make sure that URL is being computed using updates `myNum` value, as opposed to just setting it once during initialization of the service.

Also, you might want to make sure that this parameter is properly encoded for use in URL. If it's a number - you can just force it by adding `type="number"` to your `<ion-input>`. Or use 
[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before adding it to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myParams = {'foo': 'hi there', 'bar': '???'};

let u = new URLSearchParams(myParams).toString();

console.log(u);
```

Comment: How to apply this? :)

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.